# Georeferenced QGIS tiff is unusable

Tags: qgis-3, geotiff-tiff

I am using Windows 10 and QGIS 3.10.5.

I had this issue a few days  and thought I had fixed it by cleaning the Registry.

However, it has re-occurred.

I load a PDF into the Georeferencer.

I reference the PDF at a few points and process it to overlay the tiff on my base map.

The output is so garbled as to be unusable. (see image) The image is simply a series of black and white lines of variable width across the image.

The first time this occurred I "fixed" it by cleaning out all the relevant appdata files, by cleaning some QGIS material from the registry and by unistalling and reinstalling etc. I used the georeferencing process a few more times on a different map and it was brilliant.

However, it has reappeared when I have started a new map. In this case I did a number of iterations (5-6) of georeferencing on the same pdf to try and improve the accuracy. In one of these iterations the problem popped up again.

So far, even going back through all the steps I took the first time, I cannot fix the problem.

[image: Georeference output]

What caused it this time?

The error seems to be associated with iterations of georeferencing of the same PDF and saving to the same file.

I am obviously going to keep trying to rid myself of the issue, but this time, despite the cleaning I have done, nothing has changed so far.

I am a brand new user and no computer expert and I am still very much in the early days of trying to understand this program.

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to enter a .PDF, take the PDF to png or JPEG and check the coordinates, because there may be an error when trying to enter them

Comment: Okay - will try it and let you know.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me.  I scanned the paper map again, loaded as a jpeg this time and got exactly the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you have entered the coordinates correctly, what type of coordinates are you working with?

Comment: Manuel. I now understand this a little better, and realise it is probably my confusion about coordinates. I think I have got it sorted in my brain, but I will have a look again tomorrow morning. Thank you for your responses.